# GRE tunneling using Open vSwitch

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, gre, openvswitch

I am trying to implement tunneling as described [here](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/tunneling/?highlight=gre#connecting-vms-using-tunnels) with the following setup (without any success):

[image: test setup]

`ho1` is a host only interface. I want to connect `Nested Guest 11` and `Nested Guest 21`.

I have read some other tutorials like:

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/07/using-gre-tunnels-with-open-vswitch/

http://networkstatic.net/open-vswitch-gre-tunnel-configuration/

https://costiser.ro/2016/07/07/overlay-tunneling-with-openvswitch-gre-vxlan-geneve-greoipsec/#.YIHTG9JR2Uk

but I'm clearly missing something. I think I'm doing something wrong with those `tap` devices used [here](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/tunneling/?highlight=gre#connecting-vms-using-tunnels).

**UPDATE**

Guest1 (network interfaces)

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
ens33            UP             192.168.41.140/24 fe80::4f54:fbff:6d87:b5a7/64
ens34            UP             192.168.239.128/24 fe80::761f:aa88:a28a:aeba/64
virbr1           DOWN           192.168.100.1/24
virbr1-nic       DOWN
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24
virbr0-nic       DOWN
virbr2           DOWN           192.168.10.1/24
virbr2-nic       DOWN
vboxnet0         UP             192.168.56.1/24 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0/64
ovs-system       DOWN
br0              DOWN
tap0             DOWN           10.1.1.1/8 fe80::9401:52ff:fe46:86e6/64
br1              DOWN
```

`ovs-vsctl show` (I have removed other ports right now)

```
    Bridge br1
        Port br1
            Interface br1
                type: internal
    Bridge br0
        Port br0
            Interface br0
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.15.0"
```

According to [this](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/tunneling/?highlight=gre#connecting-vms-using-tunnels) I should add a tap interface to `br0`, this command: `ovs-vsctl add-port br0 tap0`. I created `tap0` with this command: `ip tuntap add mode tap tap0`. Here is the problem. I don't know what IP address I should use for the tap, or should I even assign it an address? and then how to connect it to the nested guest. I use VirtualBox for the nested guests and I tired to attach to bridge adapter on VirtualBox. In this case the nested guest didn't get and IP address.

Another thing that I don't understand from the picture [here](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/howto/tunneling/?highlight=gre#connecting-vms-using-tunnels), is that how `br0` is connected to the outside world (transport network) if I don't add `eth0` to `br0`?

**UPDATE 2**

I also tried to use hostonly interface `vboxnetX` for the nested guest. In this case the nested guest had an IP address but when I added `vboxnetX` to `br0` I lost connection between the guest and the nested guest.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to get a little more specific than "without success" - we cannot see your configuration, logs and test results.

Comment: @anx I have update the question. If there is any particular info that I should add please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. [This](https://serverfault.com/a/623529/646403) answer helped me. I had two problems with my config.

First, I should have added an IP address for the nested guests. With `tap0` up and connected to the nested guest, I configured a static IP for the nested guest.

Second, I noticed that I have a duplicate MAC address. That was because I had cloned the `Guest1` after the installation of the `Nested Guest 11`, so `Nested Guest11` and `Nested Guest21` had the same MAC address. I changed the MAC address of `Nested Guest21` and tried again.

It didn't worked at first. I was forced to restart `Guest1` because of a crash. After that I tried again. This time the nested VMs were able to ping each other.

My configuration:

**Guest 1**

`ovs-vsctl show`

```
Bridge br0
    Port gre0
        Interface gre0
            type: gre
            options: {remote_ip="192.168.239.129"}
    Port tap0
        Interface tap0
    Port br0
        Interface br0
            type: internal
ovs_version: "2.15.0"
```

`ip -br a`

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
ens33            UP             192.168.41.140/24 fe80::4f54:fbff:6d87:b5a7/64
ens34            UP             192.168.239.128/24 fe80::761f:aa88:a28a:aeba/64
virbr2           DOWN           192.168.10.1/24
virbr2-nic       DOWN
virbr1           DOWN           192.168.100.1/24
virbr1-nic       DOWN
virbr0           DOWN           192.168.122.1/24
virbr0-nic       DOWN
vboxnet0         DOWN
ovs-system       DOWN
br0              DOWN
gre0@NONE        DOWN
gretap0@NONE     DOWN
erspan0@NONE     DOWN
gre_sys@NONE     UNKNOWN        fe80::989f:9eff:fe5d:d7ce/64
tap0             UP             fe80::9401:52ff:fe46:86e6/64
```

*Nested Guest11*

[image]

**Guest2**

`ovs-vsctl show`

```
Bridge br0
    Port tap0
        Interface tap0
    Port gre0
        Interface gre0
            type: gre
            options: {remote_ip="192.168.239.128"}
    Port br0
        Interface br0
            type: internal
ovs_version: "2.15.0"
```

*Nested Guest21*

[image]

Forgot to add that in this case too, there is no connection between guest and nested guest, which I think is expected.